# captured image not showing in uiimageView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a uibutton to trigger an iphone's camera to grab an image, and I have a uiimageView in same view to show captured image, but it not showing anything after capturing.

Any solution?

Comment: We could help you if we could see some code...

Answer (score 0):

here's my code:

- (IBAction)grabImage:(id)sender{

> 

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.allowsImageEditing = YES;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
[self presentModalViewController: picker animated:YES];
[picker release];
```

}

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
      didFinishPickingImage : (UIImage *)image
                 editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
    cameraImageView.image = image;
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}

> 